# SAS how to get the first several rows by criteria

Tags: group-by, sas

In SAS, I want to obtain the first several rows by two variables `class` and `student`.

Here is my data:

```
class   student          course           note
 1       A                 001             10
 1       A                 002             14
 1       B                 001             12
 1       B                 002             8
 2       C                 001             6
 2       C                 002             17
 2       D                 003             9
 3       E                 003             13
```

I want to get the data of the first student of each class, that means the data of student A, C, E:

```
class   student          course           note
 1       A                 001             10
 1       A                 002             14
 2       C                 001             6
 2       C                 002             17
 3       E                 003             13
```

I have tried

`if first.class then flag_first=1; else flag_first=0;`

but this gets only the first row of each class.

Hope to get your answers.

Comment: Your else is part of the issue. Play around with that using first.student as well and a retain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using first logic is correct.

```
Data want;
Set have;
By class student;

 Retain flag;

 If first.class then flag =1;
 Else if first.student then flag=0;

  If flag=1 then output;
 Run;
```